# PEG parser library on Windows OS

Tags: c++, peg

Are there any Parsing Expression Grammar (PEG) C++ libraries for Windows? I've tried in vain to compile pegc/legc, pegc with MS Visual Studio. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had good luck with [Boost.Spirit.Qi](http://boost-spirit.com/home/), which should work reasonably well with recent versions of the Microsoft compiler. Be forewarned, though: there is a learning curve.

If you just want a parser generator, also have a look at this related question: [Is the ANTLR parser generator best for a C++ app with constrained memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770577/is-the-antlr-parser-generator-best-for-a-c-app-with-constrained-memory)

Comment: :D I should have a look at ANTLR first! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a search engine. You will find a wiki page about [PEGs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar) and there you will find a [list of libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar#Implementations) implementing PEGs. One of them is [Boost.Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/).

Comment: I've already known it. But it's hard to understand Boost.Spirit in an afternoon. :( Anyway, thank you!